# How do I fix this ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java

for my program (I'm trying to run a private server source code for a game server), when I try to run the file as a Java Application it gives me the following error:

```
[Launcher] Initing Cache...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at com.rs.utils.huffman.Huffman.init(Huffman.java:15)
    at com.rs.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:65)
```

Now, I'm not sure if I'm supposed to change something within the Cache? But here is the line that it is giving the error:

```
byte[] huffmanFile = Cache.STORE.getIndexes()[10].getFile(Cache.STORE
        .getIndexes()[10].getArchiveId("huffman"));
```

Comment: You will handle the Exception using the try catch block

Answer (score 1):

you can check size before trying to access it

```
if(Cache.STORE.getIndexes().length > 10){
byte[] huffmanFile = Cache.STORE.getIndexes()[10].getFile(Cache.STORE
    .getIndexes()[10].getArchiveId("huffman"));
}
```

Comment: Hey Crack, I tried this. It says "The Operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) Index[], int"

Comment: I forgot to add the length, edited my answer, please try now

Answer (score 1):

Check the size of your array by the following manner:

```
Cache.STORE.getIndexes().length > 10
```

So your code will look like:

```
if(Cache.STORE.getIndexes().length > 10)
   byte[] huffmanFile = Cache.STORE.getIndexes()[10].getFile(Cache.STORE
        .getIndexes()[10].getArchiveId("huffman"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct check is `Cache.STORE.getIndexes().length > 10`. This is small code to clarify it:

**1** Method to get required index from array with array length checking:

```
private static Cache.Index getIndex(Cache cache, int id) {
    Cache.Index[] indices = cache.getIndexes();
    return indices.length > id ? indices[id] : null;
}
```

**2** This is required index as named constant:

```
private static final int ID_HUFFMAN = 10;
```

**3** This is the code from you answer but not in one line (to make it absolute clear):

```
Cache.Index huffman = getIndex(Cache.STORE, ID_HUFFMAN);

if (huffman != null) {
    String archiveId = huffman.getArchiveId("huffman");
    byte[] huffmanFile = huffman.getFile(archiveId);
}
```

**P.S.**
This is how I represent model of your `Cache` class:

```
class Cache {
    static final Cache STORE = new Cache();

    class Index {
        public byte[] getFile(String archiveId) {}
        public String getArchiveId(String id) {}
    }

    public Index[] getIndexes() {}
}
```